# Expressjs passing locals with route.render

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, express

Console log show me the active user, but I cannot use it in view, I am using plain html.

```
app.post('/',  function (req, res) {
   var user = { user : req.body.username };
   res.render('doctor_hagfish/pets',  { locals:{
   user:user
   }});
   console.log(user)
});
```

*I don't know what i am doing wrong, suggestions?* Until now i tried these syntaxes in view  `#{user}` `{{user}}`

My Template Engine Settings

```
 app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
 app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

So i used ejs tags `<% user %>` and then nothing is displayed, so it means that template engine recognise it as defined var but still it is not displayed.

The problem was wrong syntax for `ejs` template engine locals
answer : `<%= user %>`

Comment: What is the template engine you are using? It is essential for the answer.  Also, you might have accidentally nested `user` inside of itself, i.e. to access the username, you need to do `{{user.user}}` (that also depends on the template engine!) as you declared variable user to be a dictionary with a key `user`.

Comment: I updated my question with template engine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be:

```
app.post('/',  function (req, res) {
   var username = req.body.username;
   res.render('doctor_hagfish/pets',  {
   user: username
   });
});
```

And inside of the template print variable `user`. Whether it is `#{user}` or `{{user}}` depends on the template engine.

Comment: I has to be something with my template engine, after your changes it still doesn't work, but when display username in console.log i see current username

Comment: Actually your comment putted me on right track so i will accept this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
var context = {
    username : req.body.username
    //Any other data you want in your view
};

res.render('view_name', context);
```